# AJAX json succeeds but success doesnt run

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get a login form to process with AJAX.  The php url is run and the user logs in but the success clause of the AJAX call doesn't run nor does complete. When I put breakpoints inside the functions it wont break when I debug it.  Why is the php succeeding but success isn't even run?

**JQUERY AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#login-button').click(function(){
    var dbg = $('#auth-form').serialize()+'&action=login';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'auth.php',
        data: $('#auth-form').serialize()+'&action=login', 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#login-message").html("test");
            if(data['auth'] == 'valid'){
                $("#login-message").html(data['msg']);
                //setTimeout(redirect(), 2000);
            }else if(data['auth'] == 'invalid'){
                $("#login-message").html(data['msg']);
            }
        },
        complete: function(data){
            var d = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(d);
        }
    });
    return e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("model.php");
$model = new model();
extract($_POST);
var_dump($_POST);

if(isset($action))
{
    if($action == 'login'){
        if($model->authenticate($id, $password)){
            //run authenticate function to authenticate user in db
            $_SESSION['id']=$id;
            $return["auth"]="valid";
            $return["msg"]="<font color='green'>You have successfully logged in.\r\n You are being redirected...</font>";
            //redirect to new page
            echo json_encode($return);
        }else{
            //login incorrect
            $return["auth"]="invalid";
            $return["msg"]="<font color='red'>ID or Password incorrect</font>";
            echo json_encode($return);
        }

    }else if($action == 'logout'){

    }
}
```

When the code completes the login form goes empty and the page stays static. I attempt to populate a div in the AJAX so that the user will no if he was logged in or not then plan on running a redirect.

Comment: How do you know if it is successful if the breakpoints don't fire? Have you tried using an inspector to look at the AJAX request?

Comment: Because I can then navigate to a page and it will tell me I am logged in

Comment: So, does the `#login-message` fills with text `test` after the login or not?

Comment: No it doesnt thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must return json because your  dataType is json, otherwise success wont fire.

You need to add header to your php script.
Example:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: Doesnt this: echo json_encode($return) mean im returning json?

Comment: Nope, it requires content-type i believe. I could test if you want to.

Comment: I added the header to the top of the php script but it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you checked what firebug says?

Comment: I am using inspector in chrome. No errors are thrown and execution will not break in the succeed clause (where I have a breakpoint)